# Двусмысленная пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Не знаю, правильно ли отобразила суть вопроса в заголовке.

Вопрос в следующем. Вот такое предложение:

*Она поздоровалась, расспросила, как мама.*

Смущает меня запятая перед "как". Нет, она, конечно там быть должна. Но смысл предложения в том, что она расспросила, как дела у мамы. Но также это может быть воспринято и как сравнение, то есть расспросила как кто? Как мама.

Существует ли какое-то пунктуационное решение для избежания подобной двусмысленности? Или ничего страшного и пусть остается так?

Comment: Решением может являться указательное местоимение. *Расспросила о том, как мама.* и *Расспросила так( же), как мама.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это предложение выглядит **однозначным**.

Дело в том, что глаголу ***расспросила*** нужен **распространитель** (дополнение или придаточное), иначе неясен его смысл. Поэтому в данном случае это именно **придаточное**:

*Она поздоровалась, расспросила (о чем), как мама.*

Но: *Она поздоровалась, расспросила обо всём, **как мама**.*

В этом предложении обособляем сравнительный оборот.